# Vaadin Sizeable.Unit strange appearance in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

I'm migrating from Vaadin 6 to Vaadin 7 and I found a strange thing during this process.
I have my Unit class and there is another enum in Sizeable interface with the same name.
When I import my Unit class and trying to use it, Eclipse automatically trying to use Sizeable.Unit enum instead of my class. 
Can anybody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all Vaadin components are derived from `Sizeable`, `Sizeable.Unit` is always in scope. You have to use a fully qualified name for your own `Unit` class.

Comment: But why it is so? It is really inconvinient.

Comment: This is standard Java scope rules, it has nothing to do with eclipse.